# How to enable autoplay of a YouTube video in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, youtube, embed, embedded-control

I am currently running a blog and trying to put an autoplay YouTube video on a post. I am using the code:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gxIv_ngpZYo?&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

But the video is not starting automatically. How can I make it run automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the first & after the question mark

Like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gxIv_ngpZYo?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```